# Why are voldermort reads so fast?

Tags: voldemort

The voldermort doc https://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/ says

```
Voldemort combines in memory caching with the storage system so that a separate caching tier is not required (instead the storage system itself is just fast)
```

What does it do with the storage system besides using SSD that makes it so fast?

Comment: Can you add the reference where this statement is written? It will be easier to answer if the citation has some context.

Comment: https://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/ at "Comparison to relational databases"

Answer (score 2):

The storage mechanism is a hash table, key-value pairs.

1. This is akin to an indexed relational table with two fields: key and data.
2. No transactions, atomic operations, constraints, or triggers.
3. Operations don't require complex locking. Single value conflict resolution.

In memory storage or caching is efficient, since each value is stored independently from a row, i.e. no empty fields in a "row".

Data partitioning distribution allows any free server with the data to respond, within restrictions.

As a storage system this is very efficient.

The drawback is the lack of features, the ones that make it fast, must be implemented on the front end, leading to an imbalance in processing loads in the layers.

For write-once(or rarely more) read-many objects, like blog posts, where most of the higher-level functions are not needed, this is a better high-traffic solution.